# React Hooks, rerender & keeping same state - how it works underhood?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

How is it possible that following function after rerender keeps the current value?

```
const Example = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return <button onClick={()=>setCount(count+1)} >{count}</button>
}
```

Logically looking:

1. initial render = we call useState with an argument
2. rerender = we call useState again with an argument

Looking at the component as a clean function, this should work.
But as I understand it, useState changes pure component into impure component.

But this still doesn't explain implementation of such a mechanism in an arrow function that does not have its own context. useState doesn't supposed to know which time in a row it's being called, if it's not hooked to parent function (like unique ID, this, callback, etc.)

React Hooks look like they break many paradigms of functional programming...

Comment: behind the scenes, React is maintaining information about all of the hooks called when a component instance is being rendered.  So that call to `useState` ends up accessing a global variable that contains the hook data for that component instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally `useState` keeps a track of whether the hooks is being initiated for he first time or not using a variable. If Its the first call to `useState` it makes use of the passed argument else it maintains its own `dispatchQueue` which it uses for updates.

As far as the below statement is concerned

```
<button onClick={()=>setCount(count+1)} >{count}</button>
```

here its not setCount that is preserving the variable, instead the arrow function inherits the count variable from the enclosing scope.

However, the setter from `useState` hook does also specify a callback method to which it passes the current value. For example

```
<button onClick={()=>setCount(savedCount => savedCount+1)} >{count}</button>
```

Here `savedCount` is being passed from `setCount` to callback method and react internally maintains the current state of the hook.