# React hook: difference between setting the state with an argument or an arrow function

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I would like to expand on the state update in the following issue

[React Hooks, rerender & keeping same state - how it works underhood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127060/react-hooks-rerender-keeping-same-state-how-it-works-underhood)

Is there a difference between the two ways of updating {count} ?
Are they strictly equivalent ?

```
<button onClick={()=>setCount**(count+1)**} >{count}</button>

<button onClick={()=>setCount(**savedCount => savedCount+1)**}{count}</button>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you expect should happen for a double click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not. You should prefer the latest, since it guarantees that the `count` your are working with is the latest version. When working directly with `count` rather than `savedCount`, it *could* have some updates still not applied.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no difference between the two.

The first one has the value of count through the concept of scoping.

The second one is getting the value from the useState hook using the callback, which always provides the latest value.

Comment: so you mean there is indeed a difference ?